# How to apply filter/specific criteria for browser UI component in Exact Synergy Enterprise?

Tags: exact-synergy-enterprise

I am creating a maintenance page where I want to select a task using browser UI component.  What I want to do specifically is to filter and show only tasks that are not done yet. Can I implement this using browser UI component? Does Exact Synergy Enterprise offer other components for this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You should create your browser `Repository Explorer` and use it in `browsefield` UI component.

Go to `System` tab, process to `Setup` tab and under the `Repository section` click `Explorer`. Locate your `Repository group`, enter it, click `Browsers` tab next to `Business components`, `Functional components`, etc.

Click `Add` and provide `Name`, `Caption`, `Caption suffix` fields. Then write your SQL query in `Query` field. The structure is:

`SELECT <column(s)> FROM <database table> WHERE <column(s)> IS NOT NULL ORDER BY <column>`.

Leave the `Column info` field empty for now. Fill in the `Result columns` field with column name which will be used as a Browser component result.

Finally, add database table name in the `Table list` field. Click `Save + Edit` column info button. Edit column names from a list shown below `Information section` and fill in `Header/Term ID` field with title, describing your columns (this will be shown in Browser UI for the front-end user). Click `Save` and test your newly created browser. If something went wrong, repeat steps from the start. Most of the time problem could be wrongly filled Column info field.

Now go to your `ASPX` page and add `browsername` attribute to your `browsefield` UI component. Doing so will set the `browserfield` component to your newly created browser component. This is that you want to see in your maintenance page when setting up the `browsefield` UI component:

```
<ex:cardfield runat="server" id="cf" caption="Item" captionid="0">
    <ex:browsefield runat="server" id="p" browsername="pbr" datasource="bc" />
</ex:cardfield>
```

Hope this gives you quick idea of what you need to do in order to adjust it to your  situation with `tasks`.